# Best laptop for Blender?

Tags: rendering

Today is August 14, 2023

Which is the best laptop for Blender?

Assuming max price is $3,500 USD.

I have researched but not found a definitive answer. Dell? ASUS Pro Duo?

I currently have a 2021 Lenovo I5 CPU with a 1050 card, but it is too slow.

Thank you.